# How to install Google Chrome on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, google-chrome, dpkg

I am trying to install Google Chrome on Ubuntu 13.04, but it does not install.
Output:

```
Selecting previously unselected package google-chrome-stable.
(Reading database ... 173123 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (from .../google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
 google-chrome-stable depends on libgconf2-4 (>= 2.27.0); however:
  Package libgconf2-4 is not installed.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libudev0 (>= 147); however:
  Package libudev0 is not installed.
 google-chrome-stable depends on libxss1; however:
  Package libxss1 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
```

Those dependencies doesn't install.

Comment: Might be related to: [Dependency error while installing google chrome on Ubuntu 13.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/286075/dependency-error-while-installing-google-chrome-on-ubuntu-13-04).